# Images not caching correctly [Nginx, Laravel, Cloudflare]

Tags: laravel, caching, nginx, cloudflare

I am trying to cache images, apparently some aren't caching at all it seems like but some are.

I use Cloudflare, Nginx and Laravel (Laravel Forge) as setup.

Here is the response for the specific image I want to cache.

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:public, max-age=14400
cf-cache-status:EXPIRED
cf-ray:3a7de7c45e2b3cd1-CPH
content-length:1572458
content-type:image/jpeg
date:Tue, 03 Oct 2017 06:39:37 GMT
etag:"59d231e8-17fe6a"
expires:Tue, 03 Oct 2017 10:39:37 GMT
last-modified:Mon, 02 Oct 2017 12:32:40 GMT
server:cloudflare-nginx
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

It always says cf-cache-status:EXPIRED

The image is quite large as it is a header image for profiles.

I added this to my NGINX config:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
expires 365d;
}
```

But it doesn't work at all..

Comment: You say you are using Nginx, but you've shown us some Apache config (incorrectly described as `htdocs`, I think you mean `.htaccess`). Which are you using, and is this config actually in play?

Comment: @Don'tPanic My bad, yes this is the .htaccess and yes it is in play as the JS files of my choice get's perfectly cached aswell as CSS.

Comment: Just bcs some files are cached does not mean that config is the one that is doing it.  The response you quote says `server:cloudflare-nginx`.  Are you sure you are using Apache?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am using nginx not apache

Comment: OK, that's the problem! :-) . I posted it as an answer.